# JComboBox inside Jtable with GlazedLists AutocompleteSupport - getSelectedItem returns null

Tags: swing, autocomplete, jtable, jcombobox, glazedlists

I'm using GlazedLists' AutoCompleteSupport to wrap a JComboBox used as cell editor for a JTable and am facing a problem to get selectedItem when I type a value in the editor that is not in the model.

The problem appears inside the stopCellEditing method, after you type something in the ComboBox that is not in the list. Even if something was typed in the editor, when invoking getItem() from stopCellEditing, null will be returned. Please see like 65 from the code below.

I would like to get the item from the editor to be able to add it to the ComboBox model.

```
import ca.odell.glazedlists.GlazedLists;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.TextFilterator;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.AutoCompleteSupport;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestComboBoxGlazedLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestComboBoxGlazedLists test = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists();
        test.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        //create the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create and add a tabbed pane to the frame
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
        //create a table and add it to a scroll pane in a new tab
        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"A", "B"}, 5));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        tabbedPane.addTab("test", scrollPane);
        // create a simple JComboBox and set is as table cell editor on column A
        TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository rep = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository();
        TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo[] comboElements = rep.getAllUsers();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboElements);
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);

        // GlazedLists
        DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox) {
            private Object originalValue;

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
                originalValue = value;
                return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean stopCellEditing() {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) getComponent();
                ComboBoxModel comboModel = comboBox.getModel();

                // this value is null when the selected item is not from the list
                Object editingValue = getCellEditorValue();

                //  Needed because your TableModel is empty
                if (editingValue == null) {
                    return super.stopCellEditing();
                }

                int selectedIndex = -1;
                int modelSize = comboModel.getSize();
                for (int i = 0; i < modelSize; i++) {
                    if (editingValue.equals(comboModel.getElementAt(i))) {
                        selectedIndex = i;
                    }
                }

                //  Selecting item from model
                if (!(selectedIndex == -1)) {
                    return super.stopCellEditing();
                }

                if (!(editingValue instanceof TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo)) {
                    //  Confirm addition of new value
                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                            comboBox.getParent(),
                            "Add (" + editingValue + ") to table?",
                            "Update Model",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo newUser = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo(editingValue.toString(), null);
                        comboBox.addItem(newUser);
                        comboBox.setSelectedItem(newUser);
                        return super.stopCellEditing();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        // needs to be invoked from Event Dispatch Thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.AutocompleteComboRunnable(table, comboBox));
        // end GlazedLists

        table.getColumn("A").setCellEditor(cellEditor);
        table.getColumn("A").setCellRenderer(new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.CustomTableCellRenderer());
        // pack and show frame
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class AutocompleteComboRunnable implements Runnable {

        private JTable mTable;
        private JComboBox mComboBox;

        public AutocompleteComboRunnable(JTable table, JComboBox comboBox) {
            mTable = table;
            mComboBox = comboBox;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextFilterator textFilterator = GlazedLists.textFilterator("firstName");
//                ComboBoxCellEditor cellEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(comboBox);

            TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository rep = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository();
            AutoCompleteSupport support = AutoCompleteSupport.install(mComboBox,
                    GlazedLists.eventListOf(rep.getAllUsers()),
                    textFilterator,
                    new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfoFormat());
            support.setStrict(false);

        }
    }

    public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value != null) {
                // this is used to extract the data you want to display in the table from your "custom model"
                TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo user = (TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo) value;
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, user.getFirstName(), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            } else {
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }
        }
    }

    public class UserInfo {

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public UserInfo(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    public class UserRepository {

        TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo[] comboElements;
        HashMap<String, TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo> objectsMap;

        public UserRepository() {
            comboElements = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo[5];
            comboElements[0] = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo("John", "Doe");
            comboElements[1] = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo("Betty", "Doe");
            comboElements[2] = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo("Elenor", "Smith");
            comboElements[3] = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo("Helen", "Kelly");
            comboElements[4] = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo("Joe", "Black");
            objectsMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                objectsMap.put(comboElements[i].getFirstName(), comboElements[i]);
            }

        }

        public TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo getUserInfo(String name) {
            return objectsMap.get(name);
        }

        public TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo[] getAllUsers() {
            return comboElements;
        }
    }

    private class UserInfoFormat extends Format {

        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
            if (obj != null) {
                toAppendTo.append(((TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserInfo) obj).getFirstName());
            }
            return toAppendTo;
        }

        @Override
        public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
            TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository rep = new TestComboBoxGlazedLists.UserRepository();
            return rep.getUserInfo(source.substring(pos.getIndex()));
        }
    }
}
```